# How to change the displayed name when anyone of the nested menu are selected?

Tags: javascript, html, angular6

I have a nested menu which consists of different organization list. when I select any one of the nested organization. The respective name should be displayed in the parent menu name. here is my code.

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'nested-menu-example',
  templateUrl: 'nested-menu-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['nested-menu-example.css'],
})
export class NestedMenuExample {}
```

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="organisation">Switch Org.</button>

<mat-menu #organisation="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item value="google-inc">Google Inc.</button>
  <button mat-menu-item value="Microsoft-corporation">Microsoft Corporation</button>
  <button mat-menu-item value="oath-inc">Oath Inc</button>

</mat-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use click event of MenuTrigger item and bind name of the clicked menu item to anywhere you want. 
I edited Angular Material's nested menu sample on stackblitz. I added click event to only "Birds" menu item you can multiply this event for all menu items.

Please look for my stalckblitz sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xe6noh?file=app%2Fnested-menu-example.ts